# Draw Border around Graphics?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a Movieclip (in Actionscript 3.0) which contains some graphics, which are drawn at runtime using the mc.graphics.lineTo();
Right now I want to draw a Rectale around the drawn graphics which represent the borders of the object. Well the mc.x / mc.y is not the same as the left-top-edge of the drawn graphics, so for me the getBorders(mc); function doesnt work.

The Problem which I have is that the Rectale somehow doesnt spawn in the right location, its always off!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accroding to your need you can use `getRect` or `getBounds` method of MovieClip/Sprite or any DisplayObject

- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#getBounds%28%29
- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#getRect%28%29

Comment: sry ... actually youre right bout that but I forgot to add something to the question!

the rectale I get is correct I just want to spawn it, that it surrounds the graphics but somehow its always placed at some weird location =\